# converting float to byte in netcdf file

Tags: bash, netcdf, netcdf4, nco, cdo-climate

I have a large netcdf file with a standard float field which consists of only 0.0 or 1.0.  I would like to convert it to a byte type from the command line to save some space and also make it easier to read in the array to a byte type in fortran.

I tried to use ncap

```
ncap -s 'fire=byte(fire)' CAMS_2003-2017_frp_mask2_africa_zip.nc test.nc
```

but it just seems to zero all the fields. I was using zip_6 netcdf4 compression on the source file, I'm not sure if that complicates matters?

UPDATE: I found that ncap2 works with byte

```
ncap2 -s 'fire=byte(fire)' CAMS_2003-2017_frp_mask2_africa_zip.nc test.nc
```

But I don't understand why the two differ?  It may be a memory issue, as both ncap and ncap2 fail with memory allocation when trying to convert to "int" instead of "byte".

Comment: Do you get all zeros if you cast to `int` instead of `byte`?

Comment: Interestingly using int instead of byte leads to a memory failure.  But I discovered that byte works with ncap2...  Not sure why the behaviour is different, possibly ncap is running into memory issues with byte too?

Comment: ncap2 != ncap. Always use ncap2. ncap is deprecated. Unable to reproduce the memory failure you mention with current NCO on ~1 degree global dataset.

Comment: hi Charlie... the fire file was very, very large (3GB) so the integer memory issue was a hard memory limit I think...  for smaller files NCAP2 always works fine :-) I tried ncap at first as the machine I was on had a library issue with ncap2 but sorted now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two ways of doing this:

```
cdo -b I8 copy in.nc out.nc
```

or

```
ncap2 -s 'fire=byte(fire)' in.nc out.nc
```