# Change netcdf4 data type

Tags: netcdf, netcdf4, nco

I have a netCDF4 datafile where the time variable is stored as a float `(netCDF: 'f8', numpy: float64)` and I need to change it to a 32bit int `(netCDF: 'i4', numpy: int32)`. I have tried making the change in python

```
tds.variables['time'][:] = np.int32(tds.variables['time'][:])
```

but this hasn't worked. What is the best way to make this change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting float to byte in netcdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332613/converting-float-to-byte-in-netcdf-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with `nco`, I assume a solution with `nco` is also acceptable.. This can be done with `ncap2` (example with a NetCDF file that I had lying around):

```
ncdump -h drycblles.default.0000000.nc`:
```

gives:

```
netcdf drycblles.default.0000000 {
dimensions: 
    z = 128 ;
    zh = 129 ;
    t = UNLIMITED ; // (37 currently)
variables:  
    double t(t) ;
        t:units = "s" ;
        t:long_name = "Time" ;
.....
```

Same dump (of modified file) after:

```
ncap2 -s 't=int(t)' drycblles.default.0000000.nc drycblles.default.0000000_2.nc
```

gives:

```
int t(t) ;
    t:long_name = "Time" ;
    t:units = "s" ;
```

What you are trying in Python won't work since you cast the *data* of the variable `time` to `int`, but still store it as a `float` (you don't change the variable type in the NetCDF file). I don't see any options to change the data type in place, I guess you could copy the variable `time` to another name, create a new variable `time` with type `int`, copy the data, and remove the old `time` variable.